# How to stop duplicating subdirectories?

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, web

I am trying to solve this problem and it has been 1 week and still trying to find solution.

My website has 5 languages and I'm using following code in htaccess to redirect ?lang=xx to fake folder like /xx

The code is;

```
RewriteRule ^ru/(.*) $1\?lang=ru [L,N]
```

The problem is, my subdirectories are duplicating when I click footer links.

For example; some of my footer links are

```
server/usa 
server/canada
dc/co-location
```

When I am using English (has no fake directory, it is root folder.) there is no problem.

But when I change the language to cn, it is keeping the previous folder like;

Click to china

```
example.com/cn
```

click to server/usa

```
example.com/cn/server/usa
```

click to server/canada

```
example.com/cn/server/server/canada
```

click to dc/co-location

```
example.com/cn/server/server/dc/co-location
```

So, it is keeping the previous folder when you click to other link.

I cannot use links like ../server/canada, because when I do it, it cancels the language.

I tried to do it with following code, but it needs to be written for each language and each folder and would be great if I can do it with a single line or couple of line code

```
RewriteRule ^cn/server/server/(.*)$ /cn/server/$1 [R=301,L,N]
```

My htaccess knowledge is very limited and i could not find a way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Add a slash to the front of the links in your footer:

```
/server/usa 
/server/canada
/dc/co-location
```

This makes sure that the links replace what currently comes after the `example.org` part of your URL, instead of being added after it.

For example, on the page `example.com/page1`, the link `page2` will send you to `example.com/page1/page2`, while the link `/page2` will send you to `example.com/page2`.

This should be enough to solve your problem, there is no need for any rewrite rules.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help. I've already tried to do this.

When I add slash before the links, it cancels the language's fake directory.

For example, when we do it in example.com/ru it removes the /cn and sends connection to example.com/page1/page2. But it needs to be example.com/ru/page1/page2